# sort a vector by alternating its values in R

Tags: r, sorting

I have the following vector:

```
x <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)
```

and I would like to have it ordered by alternating the values, like:

```
1,2,3,1,2,3
```

ideally, without having to loop through the elements and assign them 'manually'.

Is there an elegant and general solution (or function) to achieve such 'alternating ordering'?
General in the sense that the vector can contain 1 to n values (not only 1,2,3) and some 'categories' may be more frequent then others.

For example:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4)
```

should result in:

```
1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,4,4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a grouping variable g and sort by it and within g by x:

```
x <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4) # test input   
g <- ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along)  # c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4)
x[order(g, x)]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 4 4

x <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3)  # test input
g <- ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along)  # c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
x[order(g, x)]
## [1] 1 2 3 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

For extracting unique values use the `unique()` function and then use the `rep()` function to repeat the sequence as often as you like.

```
x <- unique(c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4))

rep(x,4)
```

results in

```
[1] 1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Thank you! That works great for when each category has the same number of elements (i.e. the first "non-general" case)

Comment: It also works for your general case, no matter how many times each category repeats.

Comment: I don't think this gives the same output as expected.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rowid`

```
library(data.table)
x[order(rowid(x, x))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another base R option using `split`

```
na.omit(
  c(
    t(
      list2DF(lapply(
        u <- split(x, x),
        `length<-`, max(lengths(u))
      ))
    )
  )
)
```

which gives

```
 [1] 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 4 4
attr(,"na.action")
[1] 11 13 14 15
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```