# How to sort a vector by alternating its values

Tags: r, sorting, vector

How can I order this vector:

```
x <- c(4,4,5,5)
[1] 4 4 5 5
```

to

```
x <- c(4,5,4,5)
[1] 4 5 4 5
```

I am not sure. I have tried TRUE, FALSE.

Comment: Hi @TarJae! Your nice little example is easy to follow, but the title is a bit hard to parse ;) Perhaps consider rewording to make your question easier to find (more searchable) for future visitors? Related: [sort a vector by alternating its values in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67139416/sort-a-vector-by-alternating-its-values-in-r)

Comment: @Henrik. Thank you for this tip. the word 'alternating' was the one I did not find in my brain. Now I see clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `rowid`

```
library(data.table)
x[order(rowid(x))]
[1] 4 5 4 5
```

Comment: How can I put this in a map function -> does not work : ` ... summarise(data = list(ids)) %>% 
  mutate(x = map(data, ~ .x %>% 
                   data[order(rowid(data))]
                 ))`. Many thanks.

Comment: @TarJae Did you meant something like this `tibble(data = list(x, x, x)) %>% mutate(new = map(data, ~ .x %>% {.x[order(rowid(.x))]}))`

Comment: And why we have to use the curly brackets here?. Thanks master you helped solving this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379163/r-conditionally-mutate-a-variable-when-columns-match-in-different-dataframes/73379992#73379992>

Comment: @TarJae i was blocking the whole expression as it involves multiple functions and extraction.

Answer (score 1):

With base R we can use `ave`

```
> x[order(ave(x, x, FUN = seq_along))]
[1] 4 5 4 5
```